# ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть список такого вида

```
mylist = ['---', '-----', '----',
'--------------------------------',
'--------------', '-------',
'---------------------', '-----',
'-----']
```

Почему приведенный ниже код возвращает `ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack`?

```
for num, score, ping, guid, name, lastmsg, address, qport, rate in mylist:
    global PLAYERS
    player = Player(num,score,guid,name,lastmsg,address,qport,rate)
    PLAYERS.append(player)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что так и должно быть.

если вы сделаете

```
mylist = [
    ['---', '-----', '----', '--------------------------------', '---------------', '-------', '---------------------', '-----', '-----'],
]
```

то скорее всего получите то, что хотели

Comment: Да, действительно. А есть ли способ без добавления списка в список?

Comment: да, ниже какраз написали

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен не цикл, а просто присваивание:

```
num, score, ping, guid, name, lastmsg, address, qport, rate = mylist
global PLAYERS
player = Player(num,score,guid,name,lastmsg,address,qport,rate)
PLAYERS.append(player)
```

Можно написать проще, используя [оператор '*'](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
global PLAYERS
player = Player(*mylist)
PLAYERS.append(player)
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в вашем случае происходит итерация по элементам списка, а распаковка происходит для каждого элемента отдельно. поскольку в некоторых строках символов меньше 9-ти, то приосходит ошибка